# Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument' what(): stof

Tags: c++, debugging, invalid-argument

As I was writing the in the other post, I am trying to implement the K-means algorithm in C++. When debugging, I get no errors, but when trying to run the program, I get the error I mentioned in the title:

Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std:invalid_argument' what():stof

I know that this error comes when the file can't convert to float. Then, what I wanted to ask is, is there something that  I should change in my code, or would it be better to use another file format as input, instead of a *.csv file ? (obviosuly, I'm making the hypothesis that the program can't read something from the file. I don't know if that's the right reasoning though.)
Thank you everyone!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//Inizializzare il punto

struct Point {
    double x, y; // Coordinate del punto
    int cluster; // Cluster di default
    double minDist; // Distanza minima

    Point()
        : x(0.0)
        , y(0.0)
        , cluster(-1)
        , minDist(__DBL_MAX__)
    {
    }

    Point(double x, double y)
        : x(x)
        , y(y)
        , cluster(-1)
        , minDist(__DBL_MAX__)
    {
    }

    double distance(Point p)

    {
        return (p.x - x) * (p.x - x) + (p.y - y) * (p.y - y);
    }
};

vector<Point> readcsv()
{
    vector<Point> points;
    string line;
    ifstream file("Mall_Customers.csv");

    while (getline(file, line)) {
        stringstream lineStream(line);
        string bit;
        double x, y;
        getline(lineStream, bit, ',');
        x = stof(bit);
        getline(lineStream, bit, '\n');
        y = stof(bit);

        points.push_back(Point(x, y));
    }
    return points;
}

vector<Point> points = readcsv();

void kMeansClustering(vector<Point>* points, int epochs, int k)
{

    int n = points->size();

    vector<Point> centroids;
    srand(time(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        centroids.push_back(points->at(rand() % n));
    }

    for (vector<Point>::iterator c = begin(centroids); c != end(centroids); ++c) {
        int clusterId = c - begin(centroids);
        {
            for (vector<Point>::iterator it = points->begin(); it != points->end(); ++it) {
                Point p = *it;
                double dist = c->distance(p);
                if (dist < p.minDist) {

                    p.minDist = dist;
                    p.cluster = clusterId;
                }
                *it = p;
            }
        }
    }

    vector<int> nPoints;
    vector<double> sumX, sumY;

    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        nPoints.push_back(0.0);
        sumX.push_back(0.0);
        sumY.push_back(0.0);
    }

    for (vector<Point>::iterator it = points->begin(); it != points->end(); ++it) {
        int clusterId = it->cluster;
        nPoints[clusterId] += 1;
        sumX[clusterId] += it->x;
        sumY[clusterId] += it->y;

        it->minDist = __DBL_MAX__; // reset distance
    }

    // Compute the new centroids
    for (vector<Point>::iterator c = begin(centroids); c != end(centroids); ++c) {
        int clusterId = c - begin(centroids);
        c->x = sumX[clusterId] / nPoints[clusterId];
        c->y = sumY[clusterId] / nPoints[clusterId];
    }
    // Write to csv
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("output.csv");
    myfile << "x,y,c" << endl;

    for (vector<Point>::iterator it = points->begin(); it != points->end();
         ++it) {
        myfile << it->x << "," << it->y << "," << it->cluster << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
}

int main()
{
    vector<Point> points = readcsv();

    // Run k-means with 100 iterations and for 5 clusters
    kMeansClustering(&points, 100, 5);
}
```

Comment: What is the content of your file? Does it have a header? Please post at least few lines from the top.

Comment: The exception is [expected behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), you're not catching it anywhere either so that would mean that `std::terminate` would eventually get called. If reading the floats can fail (and it can) you may wish to consider using a different pattern to read them.

Comment: For Yksisarvinen, the code I posted is all the code I wrote actually.

Comment: Print your inputs before trying to convert to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: I meant the content of `Mall_Customers.csv`. And you can ping certain user by typing in comment `@` and a part of the name ;)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen  https://www.kaggle.com/shwetabh123/mall-customers?select=Mall_Customers.csv  here is the link to the file.

Comment: That file looks nothing at all like what your code is assuming.

Comment: As molbdnilo noticed, your code would try to to assign `0001` to `x` (ok) and then `Male,19,15,39` to `y` (definitely not ok). And similar for all subsequent lines. And the first line is a header, no numbers there.

Comment: Maybe I understood what the problem is, thank you really much for your help!

Comment: Maybe better to use `stod` for `double`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work now, thank you everyone for the help you gave me, in particular @Yksisarvinen and @molbdnilo  : the problem was in the fact that I blindly imported all the csv file in the program, but I was supposed to import only two columns: one was the income, the other one was the spending column.

Although now I have to figure why it shows me the final result, not in the form of "bubbles",as one would expect from the algorithm,but in the form of points being clustered on a straight line.

[image]

When trying to open the original file, the original dataset, I get the  error shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: I solved this one too. Turns out that the file I was importing had ";" in my ".csv" file, while I was required to have "," as a separator. Problem solved now